Can I define a jsdoc typedef (an object) by "spreading" existing typedefs?
Can I use the spread operator to create typedefs by combining existing typedefs?
For example- given typedefs One and Two where both are objects, how do I then create typedef Three? JSDoc seems to let me do the following, but the "spreading" doesn't seem to be properly reflected in the generated html docs:
  /**
   * @typedef {Object} Three
   * @property {...One}
   * @property {...Two}
   */

If in vanilla js we can say
const three = {
  ...one,
  ...two
}

...is there a way to similarly define object typedefs using previously defined object typedefs?
EDIT: to be clear: I am asking for a JSDoc solution and not a TypeScript solution, and my usecase here is HTML documentation generation rather than autocomplete in an IDE.

Does this answer your question? How to extend a typedef parameter in JSDOC?

Is this an XY problem? Do you want to know how to extend a typedef (X) but figured maybe spread would work (Y)? Or are you just asking if spreading is viable within JSDoc and don't care about other alternatives to extending types?

@VLAZ No, absolutely not, Intersection Types are Typescript, and are not supported in plain JSDoc.

I have no idea what the "no" refers to there. I'm still not clear what you're really asking - for extending types in general or specifically for spreading.

@VLAZ I think the OP was responding to my "does this answer your question" comment. I still think it does though

@evolutionxbox Well, they mentioned me. And if it was a response to the dupe - there is more than one answer in it.  It's akin to saying "This book full of various recipes is USELESS to me because the first recipe is for soup and I don't want soup"

@VLAZ ¯\(ツ)/¯

You both linked to a question that proposes Intersection Types as a solution. Great for TypeScript, not so much for JSDoc. Or maybe I am missing something?

You missed...the other two answers? And I linked you to a different thing - explanation of what an XY problem is. And asked if that's indeed what you have or not.

Sorry- I think there is a problem with links and ordering in the comment section here. I can see that we are all talking past each other. The link the to "XY problem" took me to the "how to extend a typedef parameter" the first time I clicked it. And we all seem to be replying to the wrong comments. Yes, I am looking for a general shorthand way to combine existing (JSDoc) types into new types.

Then I'd advise asking for the X not the Y. Also, are you sure the other two answers don't work? You seem focused on the top voted one so far. EDIT: OK, so seems two of the answers use intersection. But this one doesn't.

There are no answers on this question yet, only several comments. The solution you link to is concerned with extending (creating a subclass of) an existing typedef, rather than composing one typedef from two or more existing typedefs with many properties each. Maybe the best way forward here is to submit an answer which the hive mind can then work on collectively.
